# how can we write a function to get row number of duplicated value and get min(row number)?

Tags: python, pandas, function

```
  name    job       id_number
0  krul    painter    125796 
1  tim     lawyer     789632
2  daisy   engg       256498
3  alex    dancer     456985
4  mandy   arch       456258
5  krul    painter    125796
6  tim     lawyer     789632
7  tim     lawyer     789632
8  tim     lawyer     789632
9  daisy   engg       256498
10 daisy   engg       256498
```

output :

```
 dup_Index   min_index
    0            0
    5            0
    2            2
    9            2
   10            2
    6            6
    7            7
    8            8
```

Comment: Question is unclear to me , can you explain more ?

Comment: i need to check which row number is duplicated, like in my df  0th ,5th row number is exact duplicate. i need  index_no 0 and 5 and corresponding to that min of index number i.e  0. output should like my output table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I cannot glean from the question what the intention is behind the grouping, if you want to see the unique occurrences together with their (duplicated) indices, you can always resort to grouping.

`df.groupby(('name', 'job', 'id_number'),as_index=True).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())`

Output:

```
name   job      id_number
alex   dancer   456985                [3]
daisy  engg     256498         [2, 9, 10]
krul   painter  125796             [0, 5]
mandy  arch     456258                [4]
tim    lawyer   789632       [1, 6, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

Which you can then apply all kinds of queries to get the length and the first of the lists.

Depending on what you need it for, there might be better ways of doing this, see for instance the answer by @Quang Hoang

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `duplicated` and `transform('idxmin')` for the min row number:

```
(df[df.duplicated('id_number', keep=False)]
    .groupby('id_number')['id_number'].transform('idxmin')
    .sort_values()
 )
```

Output:

```
0     0
5     0
1     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
2     2
9     2
10    2
Name: id_number, dtype: int64
```

Comment: what if we do not have unique value('id_number) column ? can we create a unique value column for duplicate records ?